# powershell multiple column output

Tags: powershell

I have a small loop in powershell produces an object with 4 elements

> PS'>$object
> DMC   : 5061
> Conv  : 6.94%
> Sales : 351
> OptIn : 185

The loop will run twice and produce data for Team A and Team B (and per haps Teams C and D at a later date), I would like to create an output that looks like this, where I can just add columns as I need.

```
        Team A    Team B
DMC     5061      5612
CONV    9.62%     6.3%
Sales   351       320
Optin   185       220
```

I can use | format-table to get output that looks something like this

```
       DMC CONV Sales Optin
Team A 
Team B
```

I have been able to do something similar by directly manipulating Excel as a COM object but it's both massive over kill and doesn't produce what I need.

Ultimately I want to convert the output into HTML and send it as an email body (which I'm able to do if I can get the table into a format I can use).

I feel there is probably a very simple way to do this buty I'm absolutely making no headway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution here is to create a PowerShell Custom object.  You simply provide a hashtable of the values you want and away you go!

```
[psCustomObject]@{TeamName="TeamA";DMC=5061; Conv="9.62%"; Sales=351;OptIn=185} 
[psCustomObject]@{TeamName="TeamB";DMC=5612; Conv="6.3%"; Sales=320;OptIn=220}
```

It will render up like this

```
TeamName  DMC Conv  Sales OptIn
--------  --- ----  ----- -----
TeamA    5061 9.62%   351   185
TeamB    5612 6.3%    320   220
```

But you wanted these in a different format, this is where transposition comes from.  Fortunately, someone did the hard work for us, with the fabulous `Transpose-Object` cmdlet.

[It is available on github here](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/blob/master/Transpose-Object/Transpose-Object.ps1)

You use it by piping an object or array of objects into it, like so:

```
[psCustomObject]@{TeamName="TeamA";DMC=5061; Conv="9.62%"; Sales=351;OptIn=185},
[psCustomObject]@{TeamName="TeamB";DMC=5612; Conv="6.3%"; Sales=320;OptIn=220} | Transpose-Object 

TeamName TeamA                                                 TeamB
DMC      5061                                                  5612 
Conv     9.62%                                                 6.3% 
Sales    351                                                   320  
OptIn    185                                                   220
```

If you wanted to use it with your loop, then add **each teams custom object to an array, like this**

```
#start of your script
$teams= new-object -Type System.Collections.Arraylist

forEach($team in $teams){

   #do stuff to calculate your custom object
   $teams.Add([psCustomObject]@{TeamName="TeamA";DMC=5061; Conv="9.62%"; Sales=351;OptIn=185})
}

#end of your script
$teams | Transpose-Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1)

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    DMC = "objvalue here"
    Conv = "objvalue here"
    Sales = "objvalue here"
    OptIn = "objvalue here"}
```